# Need help to understand elasticsearch mapping output

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic schema which defines a field, action, as 'keyword'. However, when I query the mapping /flowlog-2022-10-18/_mapping, it returns the field as 'text'. I am not able to understand the output. Why does the type comes as 'text' and not as 'keyword'? What is the 'field' part in the mapping output? Why is there a 'keyword' part inside the 'field' part?

## Excerpt from the schema

```
{
        "index_patterns": [
                "flowlog*",
                "flowobsrv*"
        ],
        "settings": {
                "number_of_shards": 5,
                "analysis": {
                        "normalizer": {
                                "lower": {
                                        "type": "custom",
                                        "filter": [
                                                "lowercase"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                }
        },
        "mappings": {
                "properties": {
                        "id": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "action": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                        },
```

## Excerpt from the mapping output

```
{
    "flowlog-2022-10-18": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "action": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
```

Thank you.

## Edit[To respond to @Val's question]

```
{
    "1": {
        "name": "flowlogtmplt",
        "index_patterns": "[flowlog*, flowobsrv*]",
        "order": "0",
        "version": null,
        "composed_of": ""
    },

    "14": {
        "name": "flowlog",
        "index_patterns": "[flowlog-*]",
        "order": "0",
        "version": null,
        "composed_of": "[]"
    },

}
```

Comment: It seems your `flowlog-2022-10-18` index  was not created based on the index template you're showing... Do you have other index templates? Maybe one whose index pattern matches `*` and which has a higher or equal priority?

Comment: the second mapping show that `action` field has two types `keywords` and `text` if you query on `action` field your query work on `text` rules instead if you use `action.keyword` your query will be on `keyword` rules

Comment: @Val flowdata.json is the only template I have for this.

Comment: @to_data Thanks a lot. Actually I was debugging an aggregation query which would always result in 400 error because "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead.".  I was trying to aggregate using {cardianality: "field": "action"}. After reading your comment, I changed action to action.keyword and it working as expected now. However, how is the index template resulting into this mapping? How do I force the field to be defined as 'keyword' only?

Comment: What do you get when running `GET _cat/templates?v` ?

Comment: @Val Thanks a lot for the url. It looks like there is one more index (number 14 in the output) with the same index pattern. I am checking if that is changing the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both templates have the [same `order` value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates-v1.html#put-index-template-v1-api-query-params), one is probably overriding the other. My guess is that `14` is overriding `1`.