# Understanding the difference between GET /_index_template/<template name> and GET _cat/templates?v output

Tags: elasticsearch

In elastic _cat/templates?v output, I see two templates:

```
"1": {
    "name": "flowlogtmplt",
    "index_patterns": "[flowlog*, flowobsrv*]",
    "order": "0",
    "version": null,
    "composed_of": ""
},
"14": {
    "name": "flowlog",
    "index_patterns": "[flowlog-*]",
    "order": "0",
    "version": null,
    "composed_of": "[]"
},
```

However, when I try to check the template name using GET /_index_template/, only "flowlog" returns a result but "flowlogtmplt" returns 404 error. Why does not elastic recognize "flowlogtmplt" as index template?

## GET /_index_template/flowlog

```
{
    "index_templates": [
        {
            "name": "flowlog",
            "index_template": {
                "index_patterns": [
                    "flowlog-*"
                ],
                "template": {
                    "settings": {
                        "index": {
                            "lifecycle": {
                                "name": "flowlog"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "composed_of": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

## GET /_index_template/flowlogtmplt

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "resource_not_found_exception",
                "reason": "index template matching [flowlogtmplt] not found"
            }
        ],
        "type": "resource_not_found_exception",
        "reason": "index template matching [flowlogtmplt] not found"
    },
    "status": 404
}
```

This is related to [my prior question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74222671/need-help-to-understand-elasticsearch-mapping-output).

Comment: elastic version is 8.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET _cat/templates` returns

- the [legacy v1 templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates-v1.html), i.e. the same ones you get from `GET _template/*`
- the [new v2 composable index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html), i.e. the same ones you get from `GET _index_template/*` returns

So you should try this instead

```
GET _template/flowlogtmplt
```

Comment: Thank you. GET _template/flowlogtmplt returns correct schema. But GET _template/flowlog returns nothing. Does that mean these two templates somehow got created by two different versions?

Comment: It means that `flowlogtmplt` is a v1 legacy template and `flowlog` is a new v2 composable template